# How do different strings (of the same gauge) affect the tone?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, strings, tone

Something I've been wondering quite long, but never had the time to really try it out myself: Let's say I buy two sets of strings, both with the same gauge, a cheap one and an expensive one. What are the differences I can expect looking at following:

- Durability
- Staying in tune
- Sound
- Loudness
- Anything else?

And, as a more general question: How and **why** (for example because they produce different overtones or whatever) can another type of string affect the sound, if they have the same gauge?

Comment: Gauge is essentially diameter.  Different metals, different windings, different production methods all contribute to the final elasticity as a function of wavelength. (which is what affects the overtone series' amplitudes)

Comment: I've started [a discussion about this question on meta](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-this-question-too-broad).

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of a very interesting article in Ultimate Guitar a while ago. I'll sum u the details of what it entailed:
The cost and brand of string **does** affect the tone/durability/volume etc. of your playing but guitar string production has came a long way over the years and we're pretty much out of ideas. There is difference in the quality of strings but - as long as you don't go for very poor quality strings - there is little difference really. Ever noticed how difference guitarists go for different strings? It's all about choice really. Your best bet is just trying out different brands/makes and finding which one best suits your ears and - of course - your wallet.